# CSS background Image -> Using an image

Tags: css, image, background

I am using the image below but I am using it as it is and it is not taking up the 100% of the screen.

I have thought of the following options but I would appreciate some advice on what to do:

1. Create a tile of the wood grain?
2. Create a strip of the wood grain?

**Current CSS**

```
html{
    background: url('../img/Body_BG.png') repeat-x 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Image**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `background-size: 100% 100%;` to `html` and change `repeat-x` to `no-repeat`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/jUr9E/

```css
html{
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    background-color:#0C0C0C;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a strip will give you the bandwidth gain while still conserving some measure of quality, while using a tile with x-y repeat will reduce quality and give you higher bandwidth preservation.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the radial gradient on the source image. Then create a strip with a few slats so it looks natural when repeated. To reproduce the gradient, use a [css3 radial gradient background](http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index.html). If legacy browser support is a requirement, include a transparent png for the gradient as a fallback.